# x-axis labelling with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a two dimensional (numpy)array and I plot the first column with the command plt.plot(wp[:, 0]). This shows exactly what I want and there is nothing I want to change besides the x axis labelling. For the x axis I am searching for a command which shows the area where the the value of the second column is the same and also which displays the y-number of this area.

```
[x1,y1]
[x2,y2]
[x3,y2]  
[x4,y3]
[x5,y3]
[x6,y3]
[x7,y4]
```

As u can the see in my example matrix, the entries in the second column are not unique but instead there are "regions" with the same value.

Edit: So plt.xticks(tx, wp[:,2], rotation='vertical')does work for smaller matrices but looks really ugly for larger ones:[image: small matrices]

[image: Large matrices]

So in my opinion it would be enough if each number would just occur once. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: You can customize tick labels with `plt.xticks(wp[:,0],labels)` http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html

Comment: That actually works for small matrices, but looks really bad for larger ones

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to:

- Customize the number of ticks
- Customize what to print when for a certain value

Modified from the [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/tick_labels_from_values.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter, MaxNLocator
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xs = range(100)
ys = range(100)


def format_fn(tick_val, tick_pos):
    return '{0}'.format(int(tick_val))[:1]

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_fn))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=6,integer=True))
ax.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The result doesn't look promising. I guess this only works, if the area with the same value is of the same size?

Comment: if you look at the example, you'll see that even though you're plotting a lot of points (26) you're only ticking _some_ of them (a, d, g, ...). For your case, you would have to calculate the number of bins (or "classes") before

Comment: But my values don't have the same interval length and it would be quite important to see the interval size. It would be perfect, if just the first change in the x-tick would be displayed... (e.g. 0.1...2....3.....4...5.6)

Comment: Since you still haven't been explicit about the rules for ticks, all I can do is I reckon that they are "only the next `floor(value*10)/10`, no repeat". If so, [`MultipleLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator) and multiplying/dividing to 10 should suffice. Otherwise, you might as well extend an existing [`Locator.tick_values`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/094007f04c717c67b31b3e14003873e5226ed096/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L1306)